# Cov(X,Y) from E[Y|X]=a and E[X]=b

Tags: conditional-expectation

I have a basic question that I cannot solve by myself.

Suppose I am given $E[Y|X]=a$ and $E[X]=b$

I am looking to compute $Cov(X,Y)$

$Cov(X,Y) = E[XY] -E[X]E[Y]$

I am thinking of getting $E[XY]$ through iterative expectations

$E[XY] = E[E[XY|X]] = E[XE[Y|X] = E[Xa] = aE[X]$ (a I correct?)

But I am not sure how to get $E[Y]$. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate the expectation, just as you did with the joint expectation:

$$
E_Y[Y] = E_X[E_{Y|X}[Y|X]] = E[a] = a
$$

which, together with your result regarding $E[XY]$, gives that

$$
\mathrm{Cov}[X,Y] = a E[X] - a E[X] = 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

$E[Y\mid X]$ is the minimum mean-square-error (MMSE) estimator of $Y$ given the value of $X$. in general, the MMSE estimator is a nonlinear function of $X$. If we *restrict* the estimator to be a *linear* function of $X$, that is, we wish to estimate the value of $Y$ as a (straight-line) function $cX+d$ of $X$, then it is  known that $$c = \frac{\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}, \quad d = E[Y] - \sqrt{\frac{\operatorname{var}(Y)}{\operatorname{var}(X)}}E[X].$$
Now, we are given that $E[Y\mid X] = a$ where I am assuming that $a$ is a constant. Thus, the linear MMSE estimator of $Y$ given $X$ has $c = 0$ and so it must be that $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$.